# Passing a control as a generic parameter type and inheriting from it

Tags: c#, oop, generics, controls

I have a number of custom controls that extend from existing Windows Forms controls as well as one or more interfaces designed my myself. The implementation of these interfaces is virtually identical within each custom control, so I would have repeating code such as the following:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox, ISomeInterface
{
    // Implementations of interface members

    ...
}

public class CustomButton : Button, ISomeInterface
{
    // Implementations of interface members

    ...
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do something similar to the following:

```
public abstract class BaseCustomControl<C> : C, ISomeInterface where C : Control
{
    // Implementations of interface members
}

public class CustomTextBox : BaseCustomControl<TextBox>
{
    // Implementations of interface members

    ...
}

public class CustomButton : BaseCustomControl<Button>
{
    // Implementations of interface members

    ...
}
```

This way, my identical implementations would be removed and consolidated into a single base class to reduce repeating code. Unfortunately, this isn't possible; are there any suitable alternatives I can use?

Comment: I'd guess you need to create a base `Control<T>` class to do this.

Comment: @cFrozenDeath can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, you're going to have to use composition to get the behavior you want.

Define a pair of interfaces; one is the "real" interface, and the other does nothing more than provide an instance of the first:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string Foo { get; }
    void Bar();
}

public interface ISomeInterfaceControl
{
    ISomeInterface SomeInterface { get; }
}
```

Then create an implementation of the "real" interface:

```
public class SomeInterfaceImpl : ISomeInterface
{
    private Control _control;

    public string Foo { get; private set; }
    public void Bar()
    {
    }

    public SomeInterfaceImpl(Control control)
    {
        _control = control;
    }
}
```

And modify your controls to implement the "wrapper" interface by returning an instance of the "real" interface implementation:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox, ISomeInterfaceControl
{
    public ISomeInterface SomeInterface { get; private set; }

    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        this.SomeInterface = new SomeInterfaceImpl(this);
    }
}
```

Now all of the logic is contained inside the "SomeInterfaceImpl" class, but you can access that logic for any of your custom controls as follows:

```
CustomTextBox customTextBox = new CustomTextBox();
customTextBox.SomeInterface.Bar();
```

If the behavior for your custom controls needs to vary, you can introduce a parallel inheritance hierarchy for `ISomeInterface`:

```
public class TextBoxSomeInterface : SomeInterfaceImpl
{
    public TextBoxSomeInterface(CustomTextBox textBox)
        : base(textBox)
    {
    }
}

public class ButtomSomeInterface : SomeInterfaceImpl
{
    public ButtomSomeInterface(CustomButton button)
        : base(button)
    {
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class CustomTextBox : TextBox, ISomeInterfaceControl
{
    public ISomeInterface SomeInterface { get; private set; }

    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        this.SomeInterface = new TextBoxSomeInterface(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice. My controls were actually inheriting from `ISomeInterface` and `IAnotherInterface` but using your method I easily changed it to accommodate for that. Additionally, properties within the implementations are public and used in the designer, so I needed to set the DesignerSerializationVisibility to Content and give them a TypeConverter of ExpandableObjectConverter so that I could continue to edit and use their corresponding properties in the designer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

As an example

```cs
// This would be your interface method
public static bool IsHigh(this Control mySelf) {
    return mySelf.Height > 100;
}
```

If your classes then extend `Control` (or one of it's sub-classes) you can simply call the method like this:

```cs
CustomTextBox tb = new CustomTextBox();
if (tb.IsHigh()) ...
```

Comment: This isn't an option. Note that I said "members" referring not just to methods, but to fields and properties.